# Chronometer format

Tags: android

I am trying to have a chronometer in HH:MM:SS format from XML in Android.

I have the following code but it doesn't work.

```
<Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer2"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:format="HH:MM:SS"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="91dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="316dp" />
```

How can I do? I want to set the format from XML and not from code. It is possible?
I tried to set also the propriety "digits" to 6 but none happen.
Can someone help me please!!

Comment: Don't know if it's a new Widget, if it is and you working with AppCompat you must use app:format instead of android:format. Also MM means month and SS is a special encoding for seconds, you should use HH:mm:ss

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Chronometer format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897665/android-chronometer-format)

Comment: Sorry but if I use android:format="HH:mm:ss" doesn't work.. It display HH:mm:ss instead of 00:00:00 and when I start the chronometer it remain on HH:mm:ss. How can I do? thank you!

Comment: @mekki10 If this is still an open question I would like to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437126/set-hhmmss-of-chronometer